# What makes a heist "Successful"?

Tags: the-swindle

It seems like sometimes I'll sneak in, hack a computer or two, and sneak out without being detected, then see my "Successful Heists" counter is still at 0 despite feeling like it was pretty successful.

So what, exactly, are the criteria to make a heist tick up your "Successful Heists" counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the numbers can also depend on the platform but usually:

- To get the **Successful Heist** you need **+80% of the loot**
- Also **Ghost** is **+99%** and **no alarms**

It was also discussed and tested on multiple steam threads:
ex: https://steamcommunity.com/app/369110/discussions/1/535151589911472768/